# Uploading image path into Database

Tags: php, image-uploading

I'm having an issue with uploading an image path into a database. Database called: basketball_database and table called: media, columns: id(int, auto increment), name(varchar), image(varchar)

All the images I try to upload from different directories on my computers are png files.
For some reason I'm only able to upload only 1 image and the database doesn't display the image name or the image path. Can anyone help me fix these problems? Thank you

File 1: upload_image.php

```
<html>
    <body>
    <form action="uploaded_file.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

File 2:upload_file.php

```
//connection
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "basketball_database";
$table = "media";

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Unable to connect to Mysql");
// echo "Connected to mysql<br>";

 mysql_select_db("$database")
 or die("Could not select Basketball_database");
 //echo "Connected to database";

//image extensions allowed
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    { 

    //Successfully uploaded
    echo "Your file " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " successfully uploaded!!<br>";
    echo "Details :";    
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";

    //Display Image
    echo "<img src=uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . ">";

    //Uploaded image folder
    if (file_exists("uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "uploaded/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

      }
    }
  }
else
  {
    //error message on the extension that are not allowed
    echo "Invalid file"; 
    $filename = preg_replace('/[^A-Z0-9]/','',$_FILES["file"]["name"]) . $extension;
    $logo = uploaded/$filename; 

    //insert into database
        $strSQL = "INSERT INTO $table(name,image) VALUES('$name_file','$logo')";
    mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
  }
?>
```

Comment: Here you need to check for two conditions, 1. Whether the file gets uploaded and moves either to tmp path or to the new path. This can be checked by dumping Files global.
2. IF it gets uploaded, please print the name of the file before pushing to db.
3. Now last point, please check if you missed any non-null parameters being missed out before triggering the insert statement

Comment: it seems like that you are trying to insert in to db without moving the uploaded file to your upload folder.

Comment: For the one image that does work called main2.png is located on my desktop, I'm guessing a copy of it is made and placed in my "localhost/uploaded" folder as main2.png. Then the database updates with id=123 name=(blank) image=(blank) and repeats each time I delete the image from both the uploaded folder and database id=124 name=(blank) image=(blank).

Comment: i don't understand why it only works for main2.png and not the others main3.png or main4.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good tutorial to start with [upload img with php](http://www.learncomputer.com/tutorial-uploading-files-in-php/).
And just build up from here.

Comment: I'll look through the tutorial. Thank you